# Part of my HTML code is loading inside the <title> element for some reason

Tags: php, html, nginx

I created a very simple website, just for testing. But I am getting a blank page for some reason.

Here is the code on the server side (index.php):

```
<!DOCTYPE HtMl>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>SiteNetSoft</h1>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
            <h1>SiteNetSoft</h1>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Here are my NGiNX configs:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name     www.sitenetsoft.com;

    root    /var/www/SiteNetSoft/sitenetsoft.com/;

    include /var/nginx/general/php;
    include /var/nginx/general/error_page_50x;
}

server {
    listen  80;
    server_name     sitenetsoft.com;

    root    /var/www/SiteNetSoft/sitenetsoft.com/;

    include /var/nginx/general/php;
    include /var/nginx/general/error_page_50x;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name     photos.sitenetsoft.com;

    root /var/www/SiteNetSoft/photos.sitenetsoft.com/;

    include /var/nginx/general/php;
    include /var/nginx/general/error_page_50x;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name     photos.sitenetsoft.com;

    return 301 http://$http_host$request_uri$is_args$args;
}
```

Here a screenshots from Inspect Element that I thing will be useful:

[image: Elements]
[image: Resources]
[image: Network]

My question is: Why am I getting a blank page? Also why is it putting part of my code in the title (as seen in the Elements screenshot)?

By the way I tried this in multiple browsers and I get the same result.

Also I tried with PHP and echo the code... And I am getting the same result. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you terminating the <title> anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this:

```
<title>SiteNetSoft</h1>
```

You never close your title tag. You need this:

```
<title>SiteNetSoft</title>
```

Answer (score 3):

You messed up your `title` tag: it should be

```
<title>SiteNetSoft</title>
```

and not

```
<title>SiteNetSoft</h1>
```

Notice that you closed the tag with an `h1` instead of a `title`.

Answer (score 1):

Check your title tag it is erronous

```
 <title>SiteNetSoft</h1>
```

It should be

```
 <title>SiteNetSoft</Title>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your html in index.php is munged:

```
<title>SiteNetSoft</h1>
                  ^^^^^---wrong closing tag
```

Since the `<title>` is never closed, the browser is doing the best it can to "fix" the bad html.